# How do I return an existing instance from factory_girl create?

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have two factories:

```
factory :foo
factory :bar
```

A Foo has_one Bar.

**foo.rb** has an after_create callback to create a Bar object. Currently, I'm able to get what I need like this, but it's a minimal example:

```
let(:bar) { create(:foo).bar }
```

I'd like to get the Bar object more directly, like this (which doesn't work)...

```
factory :bar_from_foo_callback do
  to_create { create(:foo).bar }
end
```

...and then just call `create(:bar_from_foo_callback)` to get the Bar I need. I thought that to_create looked like a good bet, but it's giving me:

```
undefined method `bar' for
 #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static:0x007fb85e3d79d0>
```

Is there a way I can define a factory so that it doesn't create, it just calls another factory and uses the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, although I haven't tested it extensively:

```
factory :bar do
  initialize_with { create(:foo).bar }
end
```

Note that factory_girl calls `save!` on the instance when you `create(:bar)`, but in this case it does nothing because the `Bar` was already saved while creating the `Foo`.